# jQuery get request working but ,success,[object Object] appearing in the browser

Tags: jquery, get

Apologies in advance if this is very obvious, I am a junior developer so fairly new to all this! I am using `jQuery` and have a function which is making a get request to two different URLs (no cross-domain issues), and when the get requests are done, proceed with the function using `.done()`. Essentially everything works as it should, however, I get this appearing in the browser, `success, [object Object] (twice)`. The full script below:

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPageLink = window.location.href,
            varToCheckStaging = new RegExp(/(stagin)\w+/),
            newPathString1 = '',
            newPathString2 = '';

    if (varToCheckStaging.test(currentPageLink)) {
        newPathString1 = "myurl1";
        newPathString2 = "myurl2";

    } else {
        newPathString1 = "myotherurl1";
        newPathString2 = "myotherurl2";
    }

    var getData = (function () {

        $.when($.get(newPathString1), $.get(newPathString2)).done(function (data1, data2) {

            var newProducts = (data1 + data2);
            var $products = $("#products"),
                    str = newProducts,
                    html = $.parseHTML(str);

            $products.append(html);

            $('.product-tile').each(function () {
                $(this).appendTo('.carousel_item');
            });
            $('.grid-tile').remove();
            $("a.product-link").replaceWith("<a class='custom_text_cta'>SHOP NOW</a>");

            $(".carousel_item").slick({
                speed: 1000,
                dots: false,
                arrows: true,
                infinite: true,
                appendArrows: '.carousel_item',
                prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 1366,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        draggable: true,
                        swipe: true
                    }
                }, {

                    breakpoint: 767,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        arrows: true,
                        dots: false,
                        draggable: true,
                        swipe: true
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1
                    }
                }]
            });

        });
    });
    getData();

});
```

Comment: Have a look at the example at the bottom of the documentation on [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Update: I fixed this by assigning data1[0] + data2[0] to the variable newProducts, instead of just data1 + data2. Not really sure why this has worked but it has achieved the desired result.

Comment: Because: _"Each argument (here `data1, data2`) is an array with the following structure: **[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]**"_

Answer (score 0):

The `.done()` callback of [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (`$.get()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax({ method: "get", ... })`) is called with three arguments: `data, statusText, jqXHR`

Now this part of the [documentation for `$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is relevant:

> In the event a Deferred was resolved with no value, the corresponding doneCallback argument will be undefined. If a Deferred resolved to a single value, the corresponding argument will hold that value. **In the case where a Deferred resolved to multiple values, the corresponding argument will be an array of those values**. For example:
>
> ```
> var d1 = $.Deferred();
> var d2 = $.Deferred();
> var d3 = $.Deferred();
>
> $.when( d1, d2, d3 ).done(function ( v1, v2, v3 ) {
>     console.log( v1 ); // v1 is undefined
>     console.log( v2 ); // v2 is "abc"
>     console.log( v3 ); // v3 is an array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> });
>
> d1.resolve();
> d2.resolve( "abc" );
> d3.resolve( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
> ```

Aimed on your script, this means that `data1` and `data2` will be arrays which contain the three parameters of the `.done()` callback as elements.

`data1[0]` will be the `data` part of the first `$.get()` call
`data2[0]` will be the `data` part of the second `$.get()` call

So you will have to change the following line:

```
var newProducts = (data1 + data2);
```

to:

```
var newProducts = (data1[0] + data2[0]);
```

Comment: Many thanks, that has explained why it's working now.